# Value change of Slider making chrome page unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have Slider for range change in my react application. On value change of that slider, page is getting crashed. Following error is showing in chrome :

**The following page(s) have become unresponsive. You can wait for them to become responsive or kill them.**

Short code overview :
React code handler for Slider (MUI) :

```
 const handleRangeChange = useCallback(
    (sensorConfiguration) => {
      setSensorConfigurations({
        ...sensorConfigurations,
        ...sensorConfiguration,
      });
      onChange({
        target: {
          name: name,
          value: { ...sensorConfigurations, ...sensorConfiguration },
        },
      });
    },
    [sensorConfigurations, name, onChange]

  const handleTemperatureChange = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      handleRangeChange({ TEMPERATURE: value });
    },
    [handleRangeChange]
  );

  return (
     <SensorRange
                range={sensorConfigurations.TEMPERATURE}
                min={DEFAULT_SENSOR_RANGES.TEMPERATURE.min}
                max={DEFAULT_SENSOR_RANGES.TEMPERATURE.max}
                indicators={DEFAULT_SENSOR_RANGES.TEMPERATURE.indicators}
                onChange={handleTemperatureChange}
              />;
  )
```

Comment: You added handleRangeChange as dependency and every time any event fire dependency is firing every time and that's make it unresponsive

Comment: @AbuSufian How to resolve this conflict ? Could you please suggest way to handle this error ?

Comment: Can you put your code on codesandbox?